# Set the color scheme for current window only?

Tags: neovim, terminal, colorscheme

How can I set the color scheme manually for the current window only ?

`colorscheme` affects all windows when I use it.

My use case is that I am using neovim and I have a terminal session in one window and regular windows otherwise, and I would like to have a different color scheme for the terminal window only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change colorscheme for a single window in vim (and probably in neovim too).

But if you speak about different colors of regular neovim windows and built-in terminals, you can play around `g:terminal_color_0..15`.

Usually modern colorschemes use them to set terminal colors to match colorscheme, e.g.:

```
    let g:terminal_color_0 = '#1c1c1c'
    let g:terminal_color_1 = '#d75f5f'
    let g:terminal_color_2 = '#5f875f'
    let g:terminal_color_3 = '#af8700'
    let g:terminal_color_4 = '#5f87af'
    let g:terminal_color_5 = '#5f5f87'
    let g:terminal_color_6 = '#5f8787'
    let g:terminal_color_7 = '#6c6c6c'
    let g:terminal_color_8 = '#444444'
    let g:terminal_color_9 = '#d787af'
    let g:terminal_color_10 = '#87af87'
    let g:terminal_color_11 = '#d7af5f'
    let g:terminal_color_12 = '#8fafd7'
    let g:terminal_color_13 = '#8787af'
    let g:terminal_color_14 = '#5fafaf'
    let g:terminal_color_15 = '#ffffff'
```

I am not sure you will be able to change background though.

PS, for vim it would be:

```
  let g:terminal_ansi_colors = ['#1c1c1c', '#d75f5f', '#5f875f', '#af8700',
        \ '#5f87af', '#5f5f87', '#5f8787', '#6c6c6c', '#444444', '#d787af',
        \ '#87af87', '#d7af5f', '#8fafd7', '#8787af', '#5fafaf', '#ffffff']
```

Comment: `I am not sure you will be able to change background though.` FYI, Neovim has `:h 'winhighlight'` window-local option. So `setl winhighlight=Normal:AnotherGroup` could change background/foreground in any window, including terminal. Also, Neovim terminal fully supports syntax highlighting (while still running in Terminal-mode) just like a regular buffer.

Comment: Neovim has `winhighlight` allowing to change the color scheme per window.